# I want to write a different footer on the title(first) page and second with these specifics

Tags: fancyhdr, footer

there has to be a line above the text in the footer. and the text begins with a number and the sentence is almost like a subscript of the number.
as shown in the picture.[image]

Comment: And how is this different from the ordinary footnotes?

Comment: \foottext will produce a footnote without having a corresponding mark in the text itself.  A bottom float (figure or table) can include \footnoterule and any text you want to show.  Just don't add a \caption.